# PHP regular expression to detect @twitter then create url

Tags: php, regex

I would like to detect a string with @account/status/postid

I have found a solution to detect the @account and create the link as such:

```
$str = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $str);
```

However, I need the regular expression to include `/status/postid` and include this in the link, the final output should be:

`<a href="http://www.twitter.com/account/status/postid" target="_blank">@account</a>`

What I have tried (as I said I am completely lost and cannot find a solution online):

```
preg_replace("/@(\w+)/|$", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\2\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $str);

preg_replace("/@(\w+)/.\2", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\2\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $str);

preg_replace("/@(\w+)/./(\w+)", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\2\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $str);

preg_replace("/@(\w+)./(\w+)", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\2\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $str);
```

**edit:**

The structure of $str will be @TwitterAccountName/status/PostID

status will always be /status/,
TwitterAccountName varies, as does PostID

The hypertext reference needs to be twitter.com/TwitterAccountName/status/PostID

The text within the anchor tags should just be @TwitterAccountName

What identifies the string as a twitter page that needs to be linked to, is the `@`

Comment: The suffix goes into the replacement string, right after the `\\1` placeholder.

Comment: I've been trying to determine how to add the suffix for the last hour

Comment: So, how did the output change with each try? Have you looked at the second preg_replace parameter? Do you realize where the HTML output comes from?

Comment: Various regex that do not work. I am not very good at regex and looking for a solution on stack and online has not helped. Which is why I am posting here....

Comment: Instead of interrogating me, which is NOT the point of stack overflow, you could explain and actually be helpful, rather than trolling. As I have already stated I have tried multiple regular expressions. I would not waste my time adding a post if I wasn't lost.

Comment: How does this question make little sense? It is a clear coding issue with an expected result. What makes little sense is why you feel the need to troll. I am not lying about trying various regular expressions. They have all resulted in error. Instead of trolling, explaining the solution would have been much more helpful.

Comment: There you go, I posted a few of what I have tried above, as I stated, I am completely lost, and I HAVE spent the last hour on this

Comment: Dunno. You could have just posted that right away - instead of arguing half an hour, calling people trolls, and insisting on being begged for details. -- Turns out your actual question isn't how to detect just `@name/status/postid` but a flexible path after `@name/…/…`?

Comment: I don't use twitter so I have no idea what the URL structure is can you post what `$str` is/could be?

Comment: I added an edit that should answer both above questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still interested in an answer, this should do the trick:

```
echo preg_replace(
     '|((@\w+)/\w+/\w+)|',
     '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/\\1" target="_blank">\\2</a>',
     $str);
```

Similar to chris85 I don't use twitter so I am not totally sure of the type of strings to expect for status and postid. I assume that they are made up of "word"-characters (`\w`). You can of course change that if necessary.

One important difference from my regexp-string to yours is, that I delimited the actual regexp with a different character from `/` to `|` since the slash (`/`) would have to be masked all the time (like `\/`) and that is very tedious (`preg_replace` accepts *any* character as the regexp delimiter).

My test string

```
$str='this is a test sentence with a @twaccount/twstatus/twpostid and some more words afterwards.'
```

gets changed into:

```
'this is a test sentence with a <a target="_blank"
href="http://www.twitter.com/@twaccount/twstatus/twpostid"></a> 
and some more words afterwards.' // (no line breaks)
```

With `preg_replace()` the default behaviour is to replace *all occurences* of the search pattern. A global-flag like `g` in other regexp versions is not necessary (and will cause an error). A limit to the count of replacements can be set with an optional fourth parameter of the function.

Comment: Excellent, that you very much for the help and explanation :)